# Implementation of K-Neighbor Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning

I would like to get some feedback of my K-Neighbors Implementation using Abalone Dataset and cross-fold validation.

1. How can I make it more efficient? (No sklearn library allowed)
2. Where do you see any problems?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

column_headers = ['sex', 'length', 'diamater', 'height', 'whole_weight', 
                  'shucked_weight', 'viscera_weight', 'shell_weight', 
                  'rings']

# Data source: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/
    
abalone = pd.read_csv('abalone.data', header=None, names=column_headers)

# Store the categories

s_category = abalone.sex.astype('category')
s_dict = dict(enumerate(s_category.cat.categories))

abalone.sex = abalone.sex.astype('category').cat.codes

# Rescale the data
cols = abalone.columns[abalone.columns != 'sex']

a_scaled = abalone.copy()

a_scaled[cols] = ((a_scaled[cols] - a_scaled[cols].min()) / (a_scaled[cols].max() - a_scaled[cols].min()))


# Split the data cross validation

shuffled_index = np.random.permutation(len(a_scaled))

shuffled_df = a_scaled.reindex(shuffled_index)


# Split the dataset in cross fold validation

k = 4
folds = np.array_split(shuffled_df, k)

fold_dict = {i: df for i, df in enumerate(folds, start=1)}

def distance(row, fold, neighbors, y_col='rings'):
    row_m = row[row.index != y_col]
    X = fold.iloc[:, :-1]
    selected = np.sqrt(((row_m - X)**2).sum(axis=1)).nsmallest(neighbors).index.tolist()
    result = fold[fold.index.isin(selected)]['rings'].mean()
    return result

def root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_predicted):
    return np.sqrt(((y_true - y_predicted)**2).mean())


n = 5
scores = list()
for key in fold_dict:
    fold = fold_dict[key]
    training_set = dict(fold_dict)
    del training_set[key]
    training_set = pd.concat(training_set.values())
    d = fold.apply(lambda row: distance(row, training_set, n), axis=1)
    error = root_mean_squared_error(fold['rings'], d)
    scores.append(error)


score_metric = np.average(scores)

print(f'{score_metric:.2f}')
```

Comment: Why is `sklearn` disallowed? Is this homework?

Comment: It's for me to practice.